# Is it wise to do teaching-assistantship in a university I am not studying in?

Tags: teaching-assistant

The universities from which I earned my BSc. and MSc. degrees are not the same. Last week, a professor who knows me from my BSc. university called me and asked me to accept his teaching assistantship for one of his MSc. courses.

Despite probably receiving a letter of recommendation from him for my PhD applications;

- What would be benefits of accepting such proposal?
- Is it wise to do teaching-assistant in a university I am not studying in?

Comment: The answer to the second question depends entirely on your universities and cannot be answered here.

Comment: @user111187 how it depends?

Comment: Some universities may have different policies than others. Nobody here knows what your university's policies are.

Comment: @user111187 Yes but my question is not addressing the policy issues.

Comment: Are you currently a PhD student? Do you have further teaching obligations at your university?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have defended my masters thesis and I am now searching for a PhD position. There is no teaching obligation.

Comment: At my university the US, TAs must be enrolled in order to work for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benefits:

- You keep your contacts with the academic environment, that may be useful applying for a PhD.
- Some professors will know you, and this that may help you get a position (depending on how it is done in your country).
- You gain teaching experience.

Drawbacks:

- TA salaries are usually quite low. Depending on your background, you may be loosing money. The working conditions may also not be so good.
- You are not getting other kind of experience, that would be useful for any non-teaching job.

On a side note, it may look weird on your CV being a TA while not enrolled. This is not necessarily bad, but be prepared to be questioned about it in interviews.